# adding a colon to the print output in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to put a colon after the password1 in the next to last line without adding a space

```
favoriteColor = input('Enter favorite color: \n')
pet_name = input("Enter pet's name: \n")
num_user = input('Enter a number: \n')
print()
print(favoriteColor, pet_name, num_user)
print()
password1 = favoriteColor+'_'+pet_name
password2 = num_user+favoriteColor+num_user
print('First password:', password1)
print('Second password:', password2)
print()
print('Number of characters in',password1,':',len(password1))
print('Number of characters in',password2,':',len(password2))
```

it prints

> Number of characters in firstpass : 13

it is supposed to look like this

> Number of characters in firstpass: 13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Python 3's f-Strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)!

Here's how it will look:

```py
print(f'Number of characters in {password1}: {len(password1)}')
```

Alternatively, you can use

- [`printf`-style string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting)

  ```
  print('Number of characters in %s: %i' % (password1, len(password1)))
  ```
- [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

  ```
  print('Number of characters in {}: {}'.format(password1, len(password1)))
  ```

Comment: Official documentation: [Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)

Answer (score 0):

`print` uses the same separator (`sep`, which defaults to `' '`) between each component. If you want `print` to do the work without formatting the string to output manually, you'll need to use an empty `sep`, and add your own spaces as needed, e.g.:

```
print('Number of characters in ', password1, ': ', len(password1), sep='')
                              ^ manual spaces  ^                   ^^^^^^ empty sep
```

The alternative solution is to format your output directly, then `print` the `str` that results, e.g.:

```
print(f'Number of characters in {password1}: {len(password1)}')           # Modern f-string style
print('Number of characters in {}: {}'.format(password1, len(password1))) # Modern str.format style
print('Number of characters in %s: %d' % (password1, len(password1)))     # Old printf-style format strings
```

In all three cases, you're fully realizing a new `str`, then printing that single `str`, rather than letting `print` output each argument individually.